# How do I mock redis when using supertest in Express?

Tags: express, redis, mocking, supertest

I am building a REST API in Express and I'm trying to mock Redis in my Jasmine unit tests (using redis-mock).

If supertest is making a request to the API, how do I tell my app to use the mock Redis instead of the actual redis? .I know I'll probably need to create separate modules for redis that I can swap out somehow, just not sure how to swap it out for a regular request vs a supertest request.

Unit test:

```
describe('Instance API v1', () => {
    it('returns a list of instances', (done) => {
        request(app.default)
            .get('/v1/instance')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+authToken)
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
            .end((error) => (error) ? done.fail(error) : done());
    });
});
```

Route handler:

```
 getAll = (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
        let redis: RedisClient = request.app.locals.redisclient;

        let keys:string[] = [];
        let prefix = 'instance/*';

        const scanner = new RedisScan(redis);

        scanner.scan('instances/*', (err, matchingKeys) => {
            if (err) throw(err);

            // matchingKeys will be an array of strings if matches were found
            // otherwise it will be an empty array.
            console.log(matchingKeys);

            response.json(matchingKeys);


        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

in my previous experience, I didn't mock Redis in integration test so I can test the flow in full functionality.

If you want to mock the Redis, you must do it before you require and initiate your application in the test something like:

```
before(function() {
  const matchingKeys = '1234'; 
  sinon.stub(RedisScan.prototype, 'scan').yields(null, matchingKeys);

  const app = require('./app');
  return app.init(); // your init or whatever function to initiate your express app
});
```

Hope it helps